# Is lookaround always executed after the character expansion in Regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I've tried this

**Regex**:

```
^(?:(?![_]{2}).)+$
```

**Text:**

`abcc..abc`

`abcdefgh_`

`abcd_abcd`

`abc_a_abc`

abc__abcd

a__abcde_

`abc++abcd`

where highlight texts mean match.

The regex above is literally mean "match any line that constructed from any characters except `__`", I just wonder about evaluation process of this regex, in my understanding the process suppose to work like this

Consider text: `abc__abcd`

Evaluation process:

1. check condition `^` (match).
2. check condition `.+` (match).
3. check condition `$` (match).

So far, all regex still can match to our considered text.

4. check condition of negative lookahead.

`(?![_]{2})a(?![_]{2})b(?![_]{2})c(?![_]{2})_(?![_]{2})_(?![_]{2})a(?![_]{2})b(?![_]{2})c(?![_]{2})d`

negative lookahead executing:

```
(?![_]{2}) ab (match)
(?![_]{2}) bc (match)
...
(?![_]{2})__ (not match)
...
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, my question is about order of execution between pattern expansion and lookaround.

Comment: You did not expand the tempered greedy token, you just created some new one as the original one matches any character other than a newline that is not starting `__` sequence. You have specific characters specified. Note that the original regex consumes character one by one, not by pairs.

Comment: @stribizhev Sorry, I don't understand, I have not much deep knowledge about execution process in regex, If you know how my regex actually work, please answer below step by step.

Comment: Have a look at the original question answer, I think it is explained well there.

Comment: Also, a [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is  a must read here. When a lookahead is checking for consecutive `__`, the regex index is standing still where it was: right before each symbol. It checks and returns true or false before going forward.

Comment: you can put your regex in [this website](https://regex101.com/), it can debug regex match step.

Comment: @stribizhev Thank you a lot for your advice, It's indeed improve my knowledge. May I ask you one question? Can we categorize element in the regex into two types which are 1) pattern 2) validator (lookaround)? because I think, in theory lookaround is not regex but it's just a feature of  validation.

Comment: A look-around is also a pattern. Validation is a domain where regular expressions can be used.